# != does not work in my program. tic tac toe

Tags: python

I'm trying to use != but for some reason it does not work for me.

> if Kord[4] != "O" or Kord[4] != "X":
>
> print "Computer Take Cord_4"

I'm programming tic tac toe, and Kord[4] is the brick in the middle. X and O is the player, and computer's inputs, and what I want is that IF there is an X or O in that field, then I want the program to skip it, but it does not.

If the area is blank, then the computer will try to take that area, but IF its is already taken by me OR the computer, then the computer will still try to take it.

Comment: You statement always evaluates to `True`. I think you want `and` instead of `or`. Or you just want to say `==` instead of `!=` depending on what you are trying to accomplish in the `if` block.

Comment: If it's equal to `O` then it's not equal to `X` so it's true... The correct - you need `and` instead... or better yet `if Kord[4] not in 'XO'`

Comment: I think you should use `and` instead of `or`. Like this ...`if Kord[4] != "O" and Kord[4] != "X":`

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is always true, you need to use AND operator for the check.

```
>>> Kord = range(9)
>>> Kord
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> Kord[4] != "O" or Kord[4] != "X"
True
>>> Kord[4] != "O" or Kord[4] != "X"
True
>>> Kord[4] = "X"
>>> Kord[4] != "O" or Kord[4] != "X"
True
>>> Kord
[0, 1, 2, 3, 'X', 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> Kord[4] != "O" and Kord[4] != "X"
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. It's more pythonic:

```
xo = ('X', 'O')

if Kord[4] not in xo:
 print "Computer Take Cord_4"
```